# Title in odoo 9

Tags: odoo, odoo-9

How in kanban view fill from databse t-att-title? Now title show

ODOO I want display name or descrption here..

```
<div class="oe_product_desc"  t-att-title='_t("ODOO")'>
      <h3><field name="name" /></h3>
      <h4>
          <field name="descrption"/>
      </h4>
      <ul>
```

Or any other solution for display text on mose hover...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `record` to access field names, so for example if you have a title field in your model you can do this

```
<div class="oe_product_desc"  t-att-title="record.title.value">
  <h3><field name="name" /></h3>
  <h4>
    <field name="descrption"/>
  </h4>
  <ul>
```